# My post "appears" to contain unformatted code

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting, warning-message

I was answering a question and always got the sickening response:

[image: I really want to swear!]

I tried seeing if I left anything out, but I found nothing... My answer is a bit long for a post and can be found in plain text format [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VA32Xib4)

I write this post for two reasons:

1. I want to see if I have something unformatted in my post
2. I want to request a feature; sometimes the site can do something *wrong*, can't it? Can't someone revise it, or something? That was *really* frustrating

Comment: there seems to be an enter missing after the `#complete code` title, might be the cause

Comment: The missing newline was my guess as well. It's not necessary for it to be rendered correctly, but the parser might think different.

Comment: @HugoDozois Yes, that seems to be it...

Comment: It's not clear what feature you are requesting here so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 17):

Indeed; I answered [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113810/incomprehensible-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatt) some time ago where the problem turned out similarly to be with the headings. As mentioned, inserting another line break after each heading should fix it in most cases:

```
#Summary
I assume you are using...
```

```
#Summary

I assume you are using...
```

---

```
#Complete Code
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
#Complete Code

    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?
It took me quite some time to find this answer and finally be able to edit this community wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4660186/revisions
(going through it thrice to catch all headings)
This is a little annoying, especially for longer answers...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402997, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341354, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277896#comment436004_341354. This is clearly a **_firmly confirmed bug_** that obviously has been known since 2014.(!) Why is nothing done to correct it? - Or could someone explain what efforts _**have**_ been done?

Comment: Note that a space is now required after the hash: `# Heading 1`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I assumed it was the code but it turned out it was the links I added. Somehow it didn't take the formatting and I had to add another line in between two of the links. I'd recommend to go part by part through your answer / post and cut each part, click somewhere outside the editor and wait a few seconds for the code to be checked again. Do that until you find the piece that causes the error and try reformatting it.

Comment: Also make sure there's a blank line between a code block and other text. Both on top and on the bottom of the code block.

Comment: Yes but for me it was not related to the code part at all. Once I removed the links I didn't have an issue, the moment I pasted them back, at any position, I had the same issue again. Very strange behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow gave the same warning. In my case it is because I wrote "=" in the text. The website thinks it's some kind of Markdown grammar...

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. In my case, I had a sentence finished with a semicolon and the next line.

I just changed the semicolon to a dot.