# Markdown editor treats 3 links in consecutive rows as code

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

See the pictures below for reference. I did go through https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but it is the same with double spaces after the lines, even with different link formats.
The only way to get rid of the error is to add extra lines between at least two of the links out of three, so no three links come after each other in consecutive rows:

[image: This one is broken somehow]

[image: This one works]

Comment: Three links in consecutive rows as you have shown are not readable. Perhaps you should be creating a bulleted list? Or perhaps you should be using descriptive text for the link, instead of the raw URI?

Comment: Although I think these links are readable as they are, the issue still occurred with any type of link formatting, so it must be something in the pattern matching for the code block, but then obviously validation fails since there is no code block.

Comment: Why the angle brackets? That's likely to be confusing matters.

Comment: The heuristic and/or error message just isn’t that detailed. It’s picking up bad formatting, and assuming it should be formatted as code. That’s not quite right here, but it *is* correct about sub-par formatting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the angle brackets were just one of the many link formatting options I've tried when I made the screenshot.

Comment: @CodyGray even when using descriptive text as you suggested, the issue is the same. Wrapping it in a bulleted list does not produce this issue, and while I see your point on why without it can be ugly with long links, it is still extremely confusing, as there are zero hints in the error message, nor did I found any guidance on how should you structure multiple links.

Comment: Hmm, okay. My guess is it's triggering on the link text itself, and that's still there in raw form even when you mark up the links. See [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277896/). As I mentioned, the heuristic isn't perfect, and the error message always assumes that the problem is a lack of code formatting, since it *is* in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: See also a possible dup on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292176/code-formatting-error/292178#292178